# Lost boot when installing Ubuntu 16.04 side by side with WIndows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I followed the Install instructions carefully, EFI was turned off and the boot sequence was set to legacy mode.  This is on a Dell Inspiron 5000.

`diskmgmnt.msc` created a partition for the ext4 file system.  When installing Ubuntu, Windows 10 was not recognized.  I continued the installation, but had to create a `/boot`, space for prom (not sure what that was, but the messages required it) and then `/` and `/home` as you would expect.  Ubuntu 16.04 installed successfully.

When rebooting the message

> "Intel UNDI"  ... "PXE-2"  ...

message comes up. So Ubuntu is booting from the net.

Can I fix the boot from Ubuntu?  Grub2 repair software?

I would like to keep Win 10, but a complete new install is an acceptable solution since I am primarily a Linux user.  This is okay since it's a brand new system.

Would a total new install from my 16.04 CD work (slick the disk) ?

Comment: More information:  F2 and F12 are disabled.  -John Redden

Comment: Two things to keep in mind: 1) When dual booting make sure to install the second OS in the same mode. Any factory installed Windows 8 or newer are in **UEFI mode** and 2) How it boots is how it installs. So, disabling EFI was what got you there. Change it back to UEFI only and reinstall Ubuntu properly: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 in UEFI mode, after installing Grub2 seems to have solved all the issues.  What got me into trouble was a post to put the boot sequence in non-secure legacy mode and the installation instructions to turn on legacy mode for third party software,  If you are installing side-by-side with Windows10, don't select that option.   I did learn that you must, at least for the Inspiron 5000 have that finger on F12 immediately.  What really through me off, was I was able to configure all the partitions, including the boot partition manually and get the Linux boot to work.  After the first Windows update, Ubuntu lost all windows capability but you could get to the command line by ctl-alt-F1.  Hopefully now Ubuntu is bullet proofed against Windows updates.  Fortunately critical work was saved at the command line on github prior to the re-install.